# not able to route log4j to smtp handler

Tags: routes, log4j

I have created a smtp handler that appears to be working if I set the AsyncRoot appenderRef to the smtp handler.  So that indicates the smtp handler is working.  However, I only want want it active in a production env.  So, I have added:

```
<Property name="isProduction">true</Property>
```

Then added

```
<Routing name="smtpRoute"> 
<Routes pattern="${isProduction}"> 
<Route key="true" ref="smtpHandlerName">
```

I expected this to route based on the property being set to true in the config file...  But appears there is something wrong with the routing...

Comment: Did you check the well-formedness of your configuration XML?

Comment: We are not using strict in the existing config, but the format looks correct, thx.  I was not sure if the pattern was correct and valid to use properties in the pattern...

Comment: You can use properties in the pattern without problems. Actually your example works correctly for me. Can you run your application with `-Dlog4j2.debug=true` and add the output to your question?